# How can you create two different but linked aggregates without resorting to one transaction?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a web application where a user can customize *one or more* sandwiches to order.
Once the user has set up his sandwich, the sandwich is added to an unsubmitted order.
The user can add to the order has many different sandwiches has he or she likes.
When the user is satisfied he can submit the order for further processing.

I have decided to model three aggregates: `User`, `Sandwich`, and `Order`.

An `Order` has a collection of `OrderItem`, each `OrderItem` references a `Sandwich` of the `User`.
A `Sandwich` as a reference to its `Order`.

When the `User` completes a `Sandwich` and submits it, a new `Order` for that `Sandwich` should be created if it does not already exist and the new `Sandwich` should be assigned to the `Order`.

You might think of the unsubmitted `Order` as the shopping cart of an e-commerce application.

I'm trying to obey the rule: *one aggregate per transaction*, but I'm having difficulties finding an implementation that models this situation clearly.
Theoretically, if I want to keep the `Order` and the `Sandwiches` consistent, I must first create an `Order` and the `Sandwiches` and then save them together. This involves creating and storing two aggregates in one transaction, which breaks the rule.

To avoid creating two aggregates at once in one transaction, I decided to create a `Sandwich` first, which will generate a `SandwichCreated` domain event. Handling `SandwichCreated` will create an `Order`, if it does not exists, and then the `Order` will add the `Sandwich` as an `OrderItem`, generating a `SandwichAddedToOrder`. `SandwichAddedToOrder` will be used to update the order reference on the `Sandwich`. This approach requires the concept of a "currently unsubmitted" `Order` for the `User`, because I otherwise would not be able to know which `Sandwich` belongs to which `Order`.

What I find "wrong" about this approach: there is a heavy "back and forth" between the `Sandwich` and the `Order` aggregates that obfuscates the actual business logic workflow. Another issue would be if the sequence of the events breaks it might leave the system in an inconsistent state, but I guess that is a side effect of allowing eventual consistency.

Is there a better approach to handle this kind of situation while still obeying the "one transaction per aggregate rule"? Additionally, how can I model this workflow in, preferably, one place so that it is not lost in many different event handlers making it hard to read and reason about?

**Edit with a clarification:**

I have decided to model a `Sandwich` as an aggregate, because each `Sandwich` of every `User` is retrieved without considering the `Order`. When the cooks prepare the sandwiches, they do not care about which `Order` the `Sandwich` belongs to, they want a list of `Sandwich` not `Order`.
A cook can choose a `Sandwich` to prepare and can change its status to something like: "Preparing", "Ready to pick up", and "Ingredients not available". Once all the `Sandwiches` of an `Order` are either "Ready to pick up" or "Cannot prepare" the `Order` is considered "Complete" and payment will be requested.
To be able to "choose a `Sandwich` to prepare" and individually change its status, a `Sandwich` must have an identity, making it an aggregate.
Another use case is that the cook is able to write a "reason" why a `Sandwich` might not be available, further cementing (at least to me) the fact that a `Sandwich` can be considered an aggregate.

It is true that I could use `OrderItem` to hold all `Sandwich` status, but I don't like this idea because the business might add beverages and delivery. Then I would have `OrderItem` for delivery and beverages with some bogus status that exists solely because a `Sandwich` has status, thus forcing other entities to have attributes that are not needed.

Comment: Tell me why we need a sandwich aggregate rather than simply an order aggregate.

Comment: @candied_orange I have clarified in the question why

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I must agree with @QuestionDriven. I still don't see why a non-aggregate Sandwich can't have a status that an aggregate Order doesn't have. Or why you wouldn't want that status for beverages. I fail to see why a sandwich needs its own identity apart from the Order. Am I missing something?

Comment: @candied_orange Beverages do not have status because once bought they don't need any additional processing (a beverage is always available it can't be "In preparation", ignoring stock). I've given identity to the sandwich so that I can change the status of a sandwich independently of the others (e.g.: sandwich 1 is ready and sandwich 2 is not available). Note that the cooks have a list of all the sandwiches from many different orders that's why I thought to give them an identity.

Comment: Beverages that are meant to be served cold can be room temperature. I’m not sure why the sandwich needs to know it’s status. The sandwich could be an immutable value object. Status could be tracked in the order. Why can’t it be done this way?

Comment: Well, it is not that it can't be done that way it is that I don't "see" it yet. I like to keep the state on the Sandwich because I don't know how I could handle other entities like Delivery or Beverage that have very different states. Having a common state on OrderItem does not look right to me. It is true that Sandwich cannot really exists outside of Order, like Delivery and Beverage. But how can I associate a Sandwich to an Order? Do I have a Sandwiches collection, a Beverage collection, and a Delivery property on Order?

Comment: A sandwich is a very dumb thing. When you make it a smart thing it stops being a sandwich.

Comment: @Gwinn: Just because a beverage won't use some of its statuses as much as a sandwich would, doesn't mean that beverages and sandwiches can't both rely on the same status set.

Comment: @Flater That is true, I wanted to keep the set specific to each entity to avoid mistakes but I could also enforce the invariant that Sandwich cannot have a Beverage state directly in the Sandwich

Comment: @Gwinn: That is the opposite of what I meant. I suggested _not_ separating the two states, nor trying to label any subset of possible states as "reserved/prohibited for type X". If you use a single status set, then there is no such thing as a "beverage state".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different approaches to untangle the situation.

1. Treat `Sandwich` as a part of `Order` aggregate, not as a separate aggregate
2. Remove the reference from `Sandwich` to `Order` and follow the one aggregate per transaction rule

If every `Sandwich` instance must belong to an `Order` (or a `Cart`) under your business rules, then I think the 1st option is the way to go.

If you want to save the customized `Sandwiches` and reuse them in the future, like for easy re-ordering, then the 2nd option would be better.

**To determine if it's an aggregate or not, you have to answer the question: "Can  a `Sandwich` exist without an `Order` or not ?"**

An Aggregate is a logical boundary of objects which can be built independently. If you can't follow the one aggregate per one transaction rule, I think it's better to rethink the model instead of bypass the rule.

Comment: I have clarified in the question why I think that a Sandwich is an aggregate

Comment: I have rethought my design and decided that, in fact, a Sandwich cannot exists outside an Order

Comment: Bravo!  I'd point out that what the customer most likely cares about is the order being prepared as opposed to the individual sandwich preparation.  As such, the status should belong to the Order aggregate anyway.